# I am trying to align three elements, on the left, the right, and the center. Center element = dynamic width, containing element = width of browser

Tags: html, css, alignment

Here is what I am trying to do: I have a `<h1>` element, a `<time>` element, and a `<div>`, all within a `<header>` that is the full width of the browser window. The `<h1>` element needs to be on the left, the `<time>` element, which changes width with the time, needs to be centered, and the `<div>` needs to be on the right.

I have been trying to work this out for a while but haven't had any luck. Perhaps it requires some javascript? I also need to be able to (I think using absolute positioning?) vertically center align them all, and they are all different font sizes.

Heres the HTML so far:

```
<header>
    <h1>blahblah.com</h1>
    <time>THE TIME</time>
    <div id="controls">
        DISPLAY CONTROLS
    </div>
</header>
```

and the CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
header {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: wendy;
}
header h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
header time {
    font-size: 30px;
}
header #controls {
    display: inline-block;
}
#controls p {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Time` is an inline element, so `text-align: center` for the header is enough to get the time centered. Further, get rid of those unnecessary `inline-block` styles.

And then the base aligning style sheet shrinks to [this fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sEw7y/):

```
header { 
    width: 100%; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
} 
header h1 { 
    float: left;
} 
header #controls { 
    float: right;    
}
```

Overflow is added to assure extending the height of the header to that of the floated elements , whichever is tallest.

Comment: Thanks very much! If anybody is interested, by adding `position: relative;` to the header, and `position: absolute`, `left: 0;` and `width: 100%` to the middle element (`time` in this example), you can get it centered properly, independent of the length of the other two left and right elements. Thanks again!

Comment: Though with this solution, you are not able to highlight the left or right elements? Any solutions?

Comment: I believe the best solution to this problem is to just `height:0;` the middle element.